# Passing Form POST values from one view to another without inclusion of URL

Tags: django, django-views

I'm building up a project that asks a user for a username and password to another site.  My thoughts are that the data will be stored in sessions.  I have no need to store the users name and password in the database.

Anyway, when I prompt the user for their name and pass with a form...

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.enteruser, name='enteruser'),
    path('success/', views.success, name='success'),
    path('<str:username>/', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def enteruser(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EnterUserForm(request.POST)
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        request.session['username'] = username
        request.session['password'] = password
        form.save()
    return redirect('main:home', username=username, password=password)
else:
    if request.session.session_key:
        username = request.session['username']
        password = request.session['password']
        return redirect('main:home', username=username, password=password)
    else:
        form = EnterUserForm()
        return render(request, 'main/enteruser.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class EnterUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = DuolingoUsers
        fields = ['username', 'password']
        labels = {
            'username': 'Enter Duolingo Username:',
            'password': 'Enter Duolingo Password:',
        }
```

**models.py**

```
class DuolingoUsers(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    last_update = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_inquiry = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

... how can I pass it into the follow up view `main:home` without exposing the data in the URL?

Edit: I've tried something like:

```
def home(request, username=None, password=None):
    template_name = 'main/index.html'
    if username is None or password is None:
        if request.session.session_key:
            username = request.session.get('username', None)
            password = request.session.get('password', None)
```

But I get a dictionary error on sessions, and I'm not entirely sure this is a good way to do it.

Comment: That is exactly what the session is for. If you are getting a key error, then you didn't put the data into the session in the first place.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I mean, obviously the data is not there, but why?  Ive done exactly what's in the docs as far as storing data in a key and retrieving it.  You can clearly see me setting `request.session['username']` and `request.session['password']` in the `enteruser` view function.

Comment: Well, one obvious thing is that you redirect even if the form is not valid, in which case the data is not added to the session. (Note also, the check for session_key is pointless, although it's not causing your problem.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have a feeling that'll be a can-o-worms :) What is the convention for checking a new session?  I really think I shoulda never used a modelform.  I have a much better time with generic forms.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Why do you want to check that?

Comment: And no, if you're not saving data to a model there is no point at all in having a ModelForm.

Comment: My thought was that I don't want to have to re-query the duolingo API every time a page is requested.  I just want to query it once per session.  I guess I could check against the username\password keys.

Comment: @DanielRoseman the model was for statistics and convenience.  It's evolved since then.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It looks like your right.  The form is not valid according to django.  I am guessing the password field is making things janky.  Guess I gotta figure out how to deal with that now.

Answer (score 0):

You could set it up via Cookies with an encryption. 
Or if you're scraping, why don't you login, then save the cookies from duolingo into the database and assign a unique identifier for the duolingo cookies.

For example table you could create the following model

```
class DuolingoCookies(models.Model):
    uniqueIdentifier = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    cookies = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True)
```

Then assign the `uniquidentifier` to a cookie which is unique. Use that information to retrieve and login into duolingo.
Let me know if this helps.

See the [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie) on setting cookies. Of course you need to improve the assignment, you could also assign the DuolingoCookies with a user_id so that it can only be accessed via Users::